# Docker cannot access volumes

Tags: linux, fedora, docker

I've installed a fresh Fedora Server 22. During the setup I selected the option to pre-install Docker.
I have activated Docker using Cockpit and installed a new container on the command line:

```
# docker run -d -h plex --name="plex" -v /etc/docker/plex:/config -v /tank:/data -p 32400:32400 timhaak/plex
```

When trying to run it I get the error:

```
+ GROUP=plextmp
+ mkdir -p /config/logs/supervisor
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/config/logs’: Permission denied
```

I've checked the container details:

```
...
"Volumes": {
    "/config": "/etc/docker/plex",
    "/data": "/tank"
...
"VolumesRW": {
    "/config": true,
    "/data": true
...
```

and the directory exists:

```
# file /etc/docker/plex
/etc/docker/plex: directory
```

everything seems to be fine.

At first I thought there was a problem with the container itself so I tried other containers as well. I encounter the same problem with each of them. They cannot create folders or files (sometimes not even read them).
In the docker documentation ("Managing data in containers") there is a very easy example of creating a new container that simply opens a shell and mounts a volume from the host:

```
# docker run --rm -it -v /etc/docker/test:/vol ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Trying to touch a file in /test results in a permission denied error.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case the problem was with SELinux. After setting it to "permissive" I was able to use the containers.

(might not be the best of solutions but works until I setup the SELinux permissions accordingly)

Update: Here is a short blog post from Dan Walsh pointing out possible issues that may arise from using Docker Volumes and SELinux:

http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/

Comment: Please complain to Dan Walsh. He was supposed to have implemented an SELinux policy to define a directory for data volumes, some time ago in fact, but as of today I don't see it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
In case anybody else faces this problem there is a blog post from Dan Walsh pointing out the pitfalls of using Docker and SELinux:

http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/

Comment: Ah, he did provide a solution, it just never wound up on my desk.